# show edit in Reopen Vote reviews

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-reopen

"This question was edited after it was closed. Should it be reopened?"

This is one type of reopen vote review.  The view shows the edited post but doesn't show the original.  Shouldn't the view show a side-by-side comparison to see exactly what was edited?

EDIT: For whatever reason, the revision tab isn't showing up in the [reopen votes view](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2714820): [image: Revision tab not showing up]

Comment: What browser are you using? Any userscript?

Comment: @Gilles SRWare Iron.  I'll try to elicit the same issue in vanilla chrome

Comment: @Gilles it looks like an Iron issue.  Chrome shows it just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I see this already:

[image: reppen revised question]

Are there circumstances where you don't?

Comment: I see `Duplicate` as a second tab for duplicates, but the last few times I did not see the `Revision` tab for those reviews.  I will keep my eyes peeled the next time and post a screenshot

Comment: @Nirk Do you mean [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2714084) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2714131)? They both show the tab for me.

Comment: @animuson I see the tab in those pages.  I will take a screenshot next time I come across a fresh review

Comment: @animuson Updated my response to show what it looks like

Comment: @animuson, Kate: What about [this review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2714820)? I don't see the “Revision” tab either.

Comment: @Gilles It appears that the tabs disappear if the question gets reopened. The *(revised)* appendage also disappears. Verified on [this review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2711200). Note that "Question" is *not* actually a tab. That title always appears.

Comment: @animuson Ah, ok, thanks. Doesn't explain why Nirk didn't see the Revision tab, even though he does see the “Question (revised)” tab.